# Is here a way to separate monolithic Maven project by creating linked modules (separate Git repos)

Tags: git, maven

My monolithic project has the following structure and this is client's requirement:

```
\
 +--modules/module1
 |             \--pom.xml
 |
 +--modules/module2
 |             \--pom.xml
 |
 +--modules/main-web-module
 |             \--pom.xml
  \pom.xml
```

Client wants all these modules embedded, so the project becomes monolithic in terms of Maven artifacts. But I need `module1` and `module2` to be shared across several other projects.

I can't specify `<scm>` section in `module1` and `module2` POMs since these modules belong to same single repo. So, I'm losing the possibility to perform `mvn release` to deploy modules to Artifactory.

I'm not sure that it is possible to link `module1` and `module2` to other repos as Git submodule/subtree since their POMs keep reference to parent POM.

Am I wrong with my conclusions?
Any Ideas on how to accomplish the desired?

Comment: You want to use module1 (for example) in a different project without including other project (example module2) ?

Comment: Correct. And have git and maven versioning.

Comment: You simply deploy all modules to a repository manager like Nexus and anyone else can consume the artifacts..out of the box without any supplemental configuration...But usually if you share modules over different projects it's better to make them standalone projects..either together or separated...

Comment: Yes, but I'm losing separate git tagging for these modules. Or not?

Answer (score 0):

The best option would have been to have separate repos for each module and combine them using `maven-dependecy` or making even making an `uber jar` if needed.

But since you cannot make separate repos, I would suggest to you to try the following.

1. Make `packaging` of each module as `JAR`.
2. Build your project and `push jars to nexus`.
3. Now you can include a particular module as a dependency in other projects for the versions you pushed to nexus.

Answer (score 0):

As the words imply there's a strong relationship between *module* and *modular* (vs. *monolithic*):

```
                  |      Module       |
                  | Tagging | Sharing |
 -----------------+---------+---------+
             Repo |   YES   |    -    |
     Modular      |         |         |
              JAR |    -    |   YES   |
 -----------------+---------+---------+
             Repo |   NO    |    -    |
  Monolithic      |         |         | 
              JAR |    -    |   NO    |
 -----------------+---------+---------+
```

Monolithic design is strongly discouraged since decades for very good reasons. I can't imagine reasons why one still should insist on it.

I hope you can convince the client that monolithic design is bad design in general. If not: RUN! ;)

**UPDATE**

A dirty hack I can think of in my nerdy mind with one repo for all projects and with the possibility of individual tagging is to create according branches (though I never ever would recommend this due to heartfelt sympathy for poor abused Git):

```
                        tag B  
main (master) --+---------o--------------
                |\  tag A          tag E   
      module1   | +---o--------------o---
                |\          tag C
      module2   | +-----------o----------
                 \              tag D
   web-module     +---------------o------
```

... and **NEVER EVER** merge any of them with `main (master)` again.